# MSTest coverage to xml

Tags: xml, code-coverage

sorry for my bad english.
I use Unit test, and i build Continuous integration. I have problem, because my CI build code.coverage. Is there any suggestion so my coverage can turn to xml ?

Thank you

Comment: Are you trying to extract coverage data from a coverage tool in XML format?  For what purpose?